# Animating a continuous line horiizontally and vertically

Tags: d3.js

I'm attempting to animate (transition) the “drawing” of an SVG path/line. The specific line I want to draw would be go 300px to the right, then continue 100px down, then 200px to the left. But it would be one single, continuous line with no curves or breaks.

Currently I can make it work by building the lines individually and applying a transition. Start at X1,Y1/X2,Y2--transition to new X2, Y2--for this duration, with this delay, and repeat, and repeat, and repeat.

Is there an easier way to do this? For example using a single SVG element rather than 3 and populate the X/Y coordinates from an array, for instance?

Any specific examples or pointing me in a general direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Here's a really simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/armarchm/c1bcc0xd/) showing how you can use a `path` in combination with `stroke-dasharray` to animate drawing. The `dasharray` specifies how long the "stroked" and un-stroked portions of the path are. We start with `0,1000` (some arbitrarily large value) and transition the first value until it encompasses the entire path. Hope this helps! Note: for uniform drawing, add `.ease("linear")` to the transition.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely possible, though it's a little quirky to get the effect you want. It involves setting a very large `stroke-dash-array` (actually the entire length of your path) and then setting the `dash-offset` (also to the length of your shape). You set this up to the point that none of the line is originally visible, and alter the dash-offset such that the line comes into view.

There's a really good article on CSS Tricks [SVG Line Animation](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) that explains the principle. I wrote a little helper to do this for me in `D3` that looks like this:

```js
d3.selectAll(".draw")
  .style("stroke-dasharray", function () { return this.getTotalLength(); })
  .style("stroke-dashoffset", function () { return this.getTotalLength(); })
  .transition()
  .duration(3000)
  .style("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

```css
.draw {
    fill: #232a29;
    stroke: #232a29;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill-rule:nonzero;
    fill-opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <g>
        <g transform="translate(0,600)scale(1,-1)">
            <!-- Circle -->
            <path class="draw circle" d="m 97.44,308.52 c 0,90.53 73.42,163.92 163.98,163.92 90.56,0 163.98,-73.39 163.98,-163.92 0,-90.53 -73.42,-163.92 -163.98,-163.92 -90.56,0 -163.98,73.39 -163.98,163.92 z" />
            </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ian--thanks for the response. I have seen the dasharray/dashoffset before, but it always looked clunky. Your modification makes it much easier to use. One painfully newbie question: I can't get the animation to run in my IE/Edge browser. It runs fine on this page, and I pasted it in JSFiddle and it works there as well. Could you take a look at my HTML file and see what I am doing wrong? [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/JSFdaniel/Lbnxe447/). First time I've replied in SO or used JSFiddle. Thanks again. Dan

Comment: @Dank I'd advocate asking a different question if you can't work it out. It's better to keep a question any one thing. If the answer was helpful please feel free to up vote and/or accept it.